# Will the mail reading program work with the quartz scheduler from background?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, quartz-scheduler

I am using the Quartz scheduler to schedule jobs. For testing purpose I ran a job which prints some value on the console. However I want to schedule a job which will read emails from a particular mailbox using imaps protocol. But I am in real doubt that it will work. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

it will work. Go on and try. Put your mail reading logic into the job class and it will read (or what ever operations you have) mails.

Comment: Can I put mail reading logic in another class and call that class from my job class. Will this work?

Comment: @user968880: Yes. It will work. Don't be afraid, just try it once. ;)

Comment: I've had success with this (calling javax.mail from quartz jobs).

Comment: No. Its not working. Its giving following error on the line
    store = session.getStore("imaps");

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore.<init>(javax.mail.Session, javax.mail.URLName)

Comment: @user968880 It seems like you are calling a method of object which does not exists for that object.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The error got solved when i inserted foll code.
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Session.class.getClassLoader());